# Play Scala MultipartFormData how do you get multiple request values

Tags: scala, playframework

The Scala Action:

```
def uploadFile = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
request.body.file("uploadedFile").map { 
video =>

  val videoFilename = video.filename
  val contentType = video.contentType.get


 amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, "NEED VALUE OF FILENAME FROM REQUEST", video.ref.file)


}.getOrElse {
  Redirect(routes.Application.smighties)
}
Ok("File has been uploaded2")
```

}

The controller (coffeescript) that calls the Scala method above:

```
    fd = new FormData
    fd.append 'uploadedFile', theFile
    fd.append 'fileName', fileName

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.open 'POST', '/uploadFile'
    xhr.send fd
```

I am able to get the "uploadedFile" request from formData in the Action. However how do you get both the "uploadedFile" and "fileName" requests?  In the action above, I need the filename to pass to amazon to have the final uploaded image name different than the original file name.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the body parser `parse.multipartFormData`, your request body is a `MultipartFormData[Files.TemporaryFile]` [scaladoc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/mvc/MultipartFormData.html)

The other parts of the multipart form data are available in `dataParts`:

```
val filename: Option[String] = for {
    parts <- request.body.dataParts.get("fileName")
    first <- parts.headOption
} yield first

// or unsafely

val filename: String = request.body.dataParts("fileName").head
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I had spend several hours without luck.  The unsafely way works.  The unsafely way works.  however, the second first part (the safely way) gives the errror:  type mismatch;
 found   : Option[String]
 required: String on the line: amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, filename, video.ref.file)

Comment: Well, you need to handle the case where `fileName` is missing from the request. In the second case you'll just throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

why not append a normal [Play form](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms)?

```
val myForm = Form(single("fileName" -> nonEmptyText))
```

and then when entering your `uploadFile` method

```
myForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    e  => BadRequest("manage error here"),
    fn => {
         // you current function here, filename will be stored as string in var `fn`
    }
)
```